# How to dynamically change Opacity for .NET Framework 4.8 C# WinForm Desktop App with WebView2 Control

Tags: winforms, webview2, .net-4.8

**Background**

I have created a custom browser by having Visual Studio 2019 create a simple WinForms (.NET Framework 4.8) application to which I have added a browser control (WebView2).

Inside the InitializeComponent I

1. have successfully set the opacity of the form to 0.5 and this works as desired for entire form and the child WebView2 control (the web browser). I can see the windows underneath with displayed web page.
2. tried and failed to set the opacity of the WebView2 browser control (the VS intellisense indicates there is no such property) and apparently this is not necessary.

**Problem Statement**

After the application is running and displaying my desired web page, however, I cannot change the opacity by changing the opacity property: this seems to have no affect!

**What I Have Tried**

Inside Form1 I have confirmed that I am dynamically changing the opacity of Form1 with a trace statement and I have tried calling Invalidate and Update (for Form1 and the WebView2 browser control after having changed the opacity) and nothing seems to make the change to the opacity take affect.

**Summary & Question**

How can I dynamically make the opacity change take affect for Form1 and its child control (WebView2) without restarting the application?

**Fri Aug 27 2021 Update with C# code**

The InitializeComponent successfully sets the opacity and I can see thru the web browser display. Yahoo!

However, my trace statements indicate that the mouse wheel is successfully increasing the C# opacity property but this is having no affect on the actual opacity.;

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.wvc = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.wvc)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // wvc
        // 
        this.wvc.CreationProperties = null;
        this.wvc.DefaultBackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.wvc.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(2, 91);
        this.wvc.Name = "wvc";
        this.wvc.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(2139, 842);
        this.wvc.Source = new System.Uri("https://bing.com", System.UriKind.Absolute);
        this.wvc.TabIndex = 0;
        this.wvc.ZoomFactor = 1D;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(2139, 932);
        this.SizeChanged += (object sender, System.EventArgs e) => { wvc.Size = ((Form1)sender).Size; };
        this.Controls.Add(this.wvc);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Opacity = 0.5D; // this works!
        this.Text = "Form1";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.wvc)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }


    const ulong MK_MBUTTON = 0x10;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x20a: // WM_MOUSEWHEEL
                mbuttonDown = (((UInt64)m.WParam & MK_MBUTTON) == MK_MBUTTON);
                if (mbuttonDown)
                     this.opacity += 0.1d; // this has no affect!
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        Trace.WriteLine("opacity="+this.opacity+" "+m.Msg.ToString() + ": " +m.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: How are you setting the Opacity of that Form, at run-time? -- There's no need to Invalidate or Update anything.

Comment: Yes: I am setting it at runtime. When I set it in InitializeComponent it works! However it does not work when I set it subsequently to a different value in the mouse-click call-back. Not calling invalide or update does not work either.

Comment: You need to show your code, not describe it. With enough context to understand what you're doing and when.